# Plotly Dash callback issue TypeError: collection_mode() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have two inputs that check if a user exists in the db using a user name or a user id. If the user exists in the db, the data gets loaded, if not, a modal pops up and the app user is asked to either get data or not.

‘Yes’ triggers a collection and closes the modal.
‘No’ closes the modal without a collection.

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])
app_theme = {'background_color_main': '#0F2537'}

app.layout = dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                        dbc.Label("SCREEN NAME", style={'margin-right':'5px'}),
                            dcc.Input(
                                id='screen_name',
                                type='text',
                                placeholder='',
                                debounce=True,
                                inputMode='latin',
                                autoFocus=True,
                                autoComplete='on',
                                disabled=False,
                                required=False,
                            ),],width=2),
                dbc.Col([
                         dbc.Label("USER ID",style={'margin-right':'5px'}),
                            dcc.Input(
                                id='user_id',
                                type='number',
                                placeholder='',
                                debounce=True,
                                # pattern=r"^[0-9]",
                                autoFocus=True,
                                minLength=1,
                                autoComplete='on',
                                disabled=False,
                                required=False,
                            ),
                        ], width=2)
        ],style={'margin-top': '15px',

                 }),

    dbc.Modal([
        dbc.ModalBody([
            dbc.Label('The requested user was not found in the database.'),
            dbc.Label("Would you like to download the user's data?" ),
        ],className='mr-1', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
        dbc.ModalFooter([
            dbc.Button('Yes', color="success", className="me-1", id='collect_user', style={'border-radius': '5px'},
                       n_clicks=0),
            dbc.Button('No', color="danger", className="me-1", id='close_collect_user', style={'border-radius': '5px'},
                       n_clicks=0)

        ],style={'textAlign':'center'} )

    ],
        id='user_collection_modal',
        is_open=False,
        centered=True,
        backdrop=True,
        keyboard=True,
        fade=True,
    )

], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('user_collection_modal', 'is_open'),
    #if user exists but data is outdated, ask if a refresh is needed
    # Output('user_update_model', 'is_open')
    [Input('screen_name', 'value'),
     Input('user_id', 'value'),
     Input('collect_user', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('close_collect_user', 'n_clicks'),
     ],
    [State('user_collection_modal', 'is_open')])
# State('user_update_model', 'is_open')]

def collection_mode(input_screen_name, input_user_id, collect_user, close_collect_user):
    from load.pg_db_functions import get_user
    # check if the user exists in the database
    if input_screen_name:
        user = get_user(screen_name=input_screen_name)
        if len(user) == 1:
            # if user exists and data is not from today ask if the data needs to be updated
            return not 'is_open'
        else:
            return 'is_open'
    elif input_user_id:
        user = get_user(user_id=input_user_id)
        if len(user) == 1:
            # if user exists and data is not from today ask if the data needs to be updated
            return not 'is_open'
        else:
            return 'is_open'
    elif (collect_user==1) and (input_user_id):
        from tw_procssing import tw_collect_user
        tw_collect_user(user_id=input_user_id)
        return not 'is_open'
    elif (collect_user==1) and (input_screen_name):
        from tw_procssing import tw_collect_user
        tw_collect_user(user_id=input_screen_name)
        return not 'is_open'
    elif (close_collect_user==1):
        return not 'is_open'

app.run_server(debug=True, port=8090, use_reloader=False)
```

I keep getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dash\_callback.py", line 151, in add_context
    output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
TypeError: collection_mode() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error says what the problem is

> TypeError: collection_mode() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Your function has 4 parameters, but you pass in 4 `Input`'s and a `State` (equaling 5 parameters).

It seems the `user_collection_modal` `State` doesn't have a corresponding parameter in your callback. Either add a parameter or remove the `State`.